# Angle between non parallel unit vectors

Tags: geometry, vectors

Suppose that $ u $ and $ v $ are non-parallel unit vectors, $ a = u+\sqrt{3}v $ and $ b = u- \sqrt{3}v $. If the angle $ \theta $  between $ u $ and $ v $ is the same as that between $ a $ and $ b $, find $ cos(\theta) $.

I'm stuck. Please help.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

**Hint:** Note that $\cos(\theta)\lVert a\rVert\lVert b\rVert=\langle a,b\rangle=\left\langle u+\sqrt3v,u-\sqrt3v\right\rangle=-2$. Now, what can you say about $\lVert a\rVert$ and $\lVert b\rVert$?

Comment: how do you conclude that the inner product of $a$ and $b$ is equal to $-2$ ?

Comment: $\left\langle u+\sqrt 3v,u-\sqrt 3v\right\rangle=\lVert u\rVert^2-3\lVert v\rVert^2=1-3=-2$

Comment: Is it that they lie in opposite directions?

Comment: @pseudogeek That's a possibility, but it's not the only one.

Comment: the angle between them is obtuse?

Comment: Yes, that's another possibility.

Comment: Can you give me another hint?

Comment: Use the fact that $\lVert a\rVert^2=4+2\sqrt3\cos(\theta)$ and that $\lVert b\rVert^2=4-2\sqrt3\cos(\theta)$.

Comment: cos (theta) = sqrt(3)/2?

Comment: I got $-1$ and $-\frac1{\sqrt3}$.

Comment: Got it! Thank you!!

Comment: If my answer was useful, perhaps that you could mark it as the accepted one.